# Java invoke its own private method with fix parameter

Tags: java, reflection

Before, I have a Swing class that have many if-else statements. after removing all if-else by using java reflection, i can invoke its own method successfully. However, i still cant pass  a parameter into the method. How to make the code below works with passing ActionEvent parameter?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        //Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(e.getActionCommand());
        Method method = this.getClass().getMethod(e.getActionCommand() );
        method.invoke(this);                
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void generate(ActionEvent e){
    System.out.println("Generating");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass the argument(s) as additional arguments to [`Method.invoke()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
method.invoke(this, e);
```

Comment: i have tried that and i get this exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.upd.ui._Summary.generate()

Comment: @Reusable: you get that exception on the `getMethod()` call and **not** on the `invoke()` call (only `getMethod()` can throw this)! You mention `private` in your title but your code has no private methods. **If** your method is in fact `private`, then you **must** use `getDeclaredMethod()` as `getMethod()` will *only* find public methods.

Comment: You just help me answered the other question in my head. I wanted to have that method as private because exposing this to others will definitely create further question on why this method is public! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Method method = this.getClass().getMethod(e.getActionCommand() );
```

reflects a method with no arguments (assuming, `e.getActionCommand()` reference the method name `"generate"`). It will reflect the method `generate()` but you want to reflect `generate(ActionEvent e)`, which simply is a different method (hint: overloading)

You'll have to reflect

```
Method method = this.getClass().getMethod(e.getActionCommand(), ActionEvent.class);
```

and then do a

```
method.invoke(this, e);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two methods, one to find a method which takes an ActionEevent and the second to pass the event.

```
try {
   Method method = getClass().getMethod(e.getActionCommand(), ActionEvent.class);
   method.invoke(this, e);  
} catch (Exception e) {
   // log the 'e' exception
}
```

Comment: it worked! thanks!

btw, this code will only work if i have the method declare as public. why it fail when i change to "private"?

Answer (score 1):

[`Class.getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) only finds public methods. You need [`Class.getDeclaredmethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29).

Also, you'll need to look for the argument type:

```
Method method = getClass().getDeclaredMethod(e.getActionCommand(), ActionEvent.class);
```

I'd prefer to do it with a helper method like this:

```
public static Method findMethodByNameAndArgs(final Class<?> clazz,
    final String name, final Object... args) {
    for (final Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.getName().equals(name)) {
            final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
            if (parameterTypes.length == args.length) {
                boolean matchArgs = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    final Object param = args[i];
                    if (param != null && !parameterTypes[i].isInstance(param)) {
                        matchArgs = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (matchArgs) return method;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Found no method for name '" + name + "' and params " 
       + Arrays.toString(args));
}
```